# Reverie body_class causing unwanted padding on Chrome/Windows

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I've been building my site using the Reverie theme for Wordpress with Foundation 3.2 installed over the included version of Foundation and it's been working great on Safari / Chrome on my Macbook (and iphone), but when I try it on a Windows machine padding becomes an issue from the body tag.

Specifically, the php `body_class('hide-extras');` is what's causing the issue. It creates an element style on the body tag of `padding-top:45px;` and it creates a break between the top-bar nav and my full width header. trying to hard code a `!padding-top:0px;` yields no result.

If I get rid of it, it creates a problems on every page, and I can't find any documentation on Reverie's / Foundation's body classes.

see: [zephyrusdigital.com](http://zephyrusdigital.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is caused by the foundation.topbar.js

On line  45 :

```
*Fixed padding-top on body* 
if (this.settings.$topbar.parent().hasClass('fixed')) {
   $('body').css('padding-top', this.outerHeight(this.settings.$topbar));
```

You can remove it if you want or work around it.